# I am facing problem while doing merge multiple branch in github?

Tags: github

when I try to marge **multiple branches** the problem occurs with 'both complicit are modified'

Comment: are you trying to merge the all branch into master ?

Comment: Can you please provide the Error what you facing when you try to merge?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.